# Iterating over list of strings in xslt, and using index

Tags: c#, xslt, xml-serialization

I work in C#.
I use XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 1.0.
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt
I use xslt in order to create xml from the data in the class MyClass
MyClass matches the template and has a property

```
 List<string> Strings
```

I need to export it this way:

```
<Line1> first string value Here </Line1>
<Line2> Second string value here </Line2>
.
.
.
```

Could someone help me in realising how to do it?
All the best
Tal

Comment: I don't get it. Can you provide a more explicit XML source sample?

Comment: You say "I have a class to match the template with a property". In which programming language is that? Which XSLT processor do you use? The interaction between XSLT and other programming languages depends very much on the particular processor, its API and the programming platform.

Comment: I'm more familiar with XSLT in Java, but this doesn't seem like the thing XSLT does. You're looking for an XML serializer. XSLT is for transforming XML to different XML. Some quick Googling found me this: [How to serialize an object to XML in C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815813).

Comment: I have tried to fix the question, I wish people here where more patient with nubies.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann i use it  to create xmls from classes, i just can't figure out this one.

Comment: @tal I wish "nubies" would read the help before posting.

Comment: @tal: This isn't a job for XSLT. You just want to serialize it.

Comment: Why do you want or need to use XSLT to iterate over a list of strings and create XML elements? That sounds more like a job for LINQ `list.Select((item, index) => new XElement("Line" + index, item))`.

Comment: Becuase that is the way all the template are written for all the xml's I need to produce from all the entities (different template for each entity). Templates should be editable by non programmeres.

Comment: Consider to show us what you currently have i.e. show us one class sample with a property or field together with the current XSLT doing the job, then we get an idea of what you are trying to do with that `List<string>` property. The usual input to XSLT is XML and not a C# class so we need to understand where/how you combine C# classes and XSLT to create another XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Maybe there is a better one...
I have created a new ExportClass:

```
public class ExportString
{
   [XmlElement("StringObject")]
   public string StringObject{get; set;}
}
```

I have created a list as property is the MyExportClass that matches the XSLT:

```
public class MyExportClass
{
   [XmlElement("LOS"]
   public List<StringObject> LOS<get; set;}
}
```

I have used this syntax in the XSLT:
The code includes index in the element's name :

```
<xsl:for-each select="LOS" xml:space="default">

 //Get the index
  <xsl:variable name ="index" select="position()"/>

  <xsl:element name ="Line{$index}">
  <xsl:value-of select = "StringObject"/>
  </xsl:element>

   //Line break
  <xsl:text> &#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Result:

```
<Line1> my first string </Line1>
<Line2> my second string </Line2>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> Strings = new List<string>() {
                    "first string value Here",
                    "Second string value here"
            };

            List<XElement> output = Strings.Select((x, i) => new XElement("Line" + (i + 1).ToString(), x)).ToList(); 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to use xslt template.